# When reading appSettings, I get key Counter from nowhere

Tags: c#, configuration, appsettings, configuration-management

I have something very strange.
I'm using ConfigurationManager to open configuration file like:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = path;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

everything works fine, but when I look at config.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys I can see key named Counter that does not exist in my configuration file, in addition to the other keys.

In the configuration file:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="test" value="23"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Any ideas please?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ar [Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98713/thomas-levesque) pointed out - you get inherited values from 'parent' configs on your machine. Sometimes you really don't want it happening. So you can use `<clear\>` element:

```
<appSettings>
     <clear/>
     <add key="test" value="23"/>
</appSettings>
```

This will prevent any automatic inheritance of `<appSettings>` collection.

Answer (score 2):

.NET configuration system uses an inheritance mechanism. Some settings are defined in a machine-level configuration file (`<.NET Framework directory>\machine.config`), and each app-specific configuration file can override machine-level settings. In your case, I think the `Counter` setting is defined in the machine.config file.

Comment: also note that there are two versions of machine.config, for both x86 and x64 versions, if you are using x64 Windows.